# Error:while viewing changes in Django

Tags: django, python-2.7, python-3.x, django-views

I am learning Django from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nAn1KpPlN2w&index=5&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBlmzzFcLgDhKTTfNLfX1IK

I have did exactly the same things mentioned in it.But still these errors are coming at the end when I restart my server to see changes in music and admin page. These errors are:

Here is an image of the command line with the errors show.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> `from django.import views`

This is an *invalid syntax* and is not a correct way to import in Python.

Instead, according to the tutorial, you should be importing `views` from your django app:

```
from . import views
```